# decode unknoun url parameter in asp.net webpage

Tags: php, asp.net, html, base64, html-encode

I have this url which has some encoded email parameters which look like this :

```
email=8b3f99fa-079c-40e3-8fe6-77fb220fc769
```

I need to know what type of encoding is it and how can I convert it?
I've tried `base64` , `html` encode/decode but no result.

Answer (score 0):

The value resembles GUID. It is a [globally unique identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) and may be a lookup key in a table where the email is stored.

Comment: but a developer used it to get the email and I'm sure he didn't access the database because the site is secure.

Comment: There is no standard way by which the email can be represented as shown. There may have been a custom encoding / encryption used.

Comment: is it possible that this is an id to database record and the developer used it to access the email field , but the site is not vulnerable to sql injection .

Comment: yes - sql injection can be avoided by following secure coding practices and still be using DB.